# what is oAuth ? and how to get oAuth key?

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am new to android and developing also I need to know what is `oauth` and how to generate `oauth key.`

I am wanting to use `oAuth` in order to use `oDesk` API.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to search by yourself for this kind of question. StackOverflow (SO) is full of this kind of question. At least, just ask "how to generate a oauth key" in order to NOT be considered as an idle consumer.

Comment: ok then tell me how to generate a oauth key ?

Answer (score 2):

OAuth/OAuth2 are protocols used for password-free authentication. OAuth2 is the newest, recommended one - it's specified in [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

Why use OAuth instead of simple passwords?

- so users don't have to remember passwords for each site
- so users won't try to use same password on multiple sites
- so you don't have to implement password management, which is hard and [even big companies fail](http://leisureguy.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/152000000-login-ids-and-passwords-lost-by-adobe/).

Additionally, sites which are maintaining some form of user data (like Google, Facebook etc.) can use OAuth to allow 3rd party applications to use that data. OAuth allows them to ask users for their consent for every piece of data application asks for.

oDesk supports it, see [their documentation](http://developers.odesk.com/w/page/38106543/Authentication-using-OAuth) for more details. What you need to do, is you have to register there and [apply for an API key here](https://www.odesk.com/services/api/apply). This API key will be then used in OAuth flow.

In Android application, you will probably use a bit modified authentication flow. This is because one step of process of getting token is for OAuth server to redirect user to your application's webpage - but in case of mobile app, you won't have web service. Often, as a workaround, you could use special `redirect_uri` value. See [Google OAuth doc](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) for a nice explanation. I'm not sure about oDesks way of doing this, though.

Finally, above all, I recommend reading RFC6749. It might take you a while, but it's totally worth it. OAuth is a quite complex protocol, and it has its issues. If you want to use it, and use it in a secure way, you have to know those little things. One trivial example is using a `state` parameter - it's not mandatory, so you might get away without even knowing its existence, but omiting it has [serious security implications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12).